# Java - how to make a timer which displays elapsing time in JLabel

Tags: java, timer, jlabel

I'm writing the code of my first Java Game right now, so far I have built GUI and I want to add some logic. In my game, user should see elapsing time for his move (begin with 10s), like 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0. I created JLabel and would like to display that elapsing time on it. My program has 3 levels of difficulty, firstly user chooses one by clicking on appropriate JButton and then user should see the timer and some options to choice and play. How can i cope with this problem? I read about Timer class in Java but still don't know how can i display counting-down time on JLabel. Maybe should I implement a game loop, but to be honest I don't have any idea how to make it.

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: I'm looking for the solution, now I think about a game loop and how to connect it with a timer maybe

Comment: this http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=25991 can get you started. However, the g.drawImage call is not done on Swing's Event Dispatching Thread, which needs to be fixed (SwingUtilities?)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a count down timer method and pass your JLabel to it along with the number of seconds to count down and a optional 'End Of Time' message.

There are lots of examples of this sort of thing on the internet but here is my quick rendition of one:

```
public static Timer CountdownTimer(JLabel comp, int secondsDuration, String... endOfTimeMessage) {                                         
    if (secondsDuration == 0) { return null; }
    String endMsg = "~nothing~";
    if (endOfTimeMessage.length>0) { endMsg = endOfTimeMessage[0]; }
    final String eMsg = endMsg;
    int seconds = secondsDuration;
    final long duration = seconds * 1000;
    JLabel label = (JLabel)comp;
    final Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
        long startTime = -1;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (startTime < 0) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long clockTime = now - startTime;
            if (clockTime >= duration) {
                ((Timer)event.getSource()).stop();
                if (!eMsg.equals("~nothing~")) { label.setText(eMsg); }
                return;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss:SSS");
            label.setText(df.format(duration - clockTime));
        }
    });
    timer.start(); 
    return timer;
}
```

If you want to change the way the count-down is displayed within the JLabel then you can change the **SimpleDateFormat** string. This method returns the Timer object so...you figure out how to stop it whenever you want (before the duration has expired).